# Ionic2 Angular2 Typescript2: When does NgModule Imports run on Cordova?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2, typescript2.0

I keep getting a "null reference" error when I try to log in on my Ionic2/Angular2 app using Google+ when I "ionic run android" (emulator or on areal device). But I don't get that error when I use a "ionic serve".

The "null reference" seems to indicate that `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` isn't being run before I try to use Firebase when running as Android.

**Questions:**

1. When does the "imports" part of the `@NgModule` declaration run on
   Cordova vs when viewing as a web browser?
2. Am I correct in my guess
   that `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` isn't being run
   in Cordova? If so, how do I best confirm?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Pages
import { ForgotPasswordPage } from '../pages/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password';
import { AuthPage } from '../pages/auth/home/home';
import { LoginEmailPage } from '../pages/auth/login-email/login-email';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { SignUpPage } from '../pages/auth/sign-up/sign-up';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TermsOfServicePage } from '../pages/terms-of-service/terms-of-service';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';

// Providers
import { DataProvider } from '../providers/data';
import { AuthProvider } from '../providers/auth';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '****',
  authDomain: '****.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://****.firebaseio.com/',
  storageBucket: '****.appspot.com',
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ForgotPasswordPage,
    AuthPage,
    LoginEmailPage,
    SignUpPage,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    TermsOfServicePage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    FormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ForgotPasswordPage,
    AuthPage,
    LoginEmailPage,
    SignUpPage,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    TermsOfServicePage
  ],
  providers: [
    DataProvider,
    AuthProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Google log in part of auth.ts**

```
loginWithGooglePlus() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      GooglePlus.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(googlePlusData => {
        let provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googlePlusData.authResponse.accessToken);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then(firebaseData => {
          // process user data
          observer.next();
        });
      }, error => {
        observer.error(error);
      });
    } else {
      this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
      }).then((googlePlusData) => {
        // process user data
        observer.next();
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.info("error", error);
        observer.error(error);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**The error (as seen in Android Studio, using "ionic build android" files)**

```
E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
             java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzy(Unknown Source)
                 at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc.getSignInIntent(Unknown Source)
                 at nl.xservices.plugins.GooglePlus.signIn(GooglePlus.java:165)
                 at nl.xservices.plugins.GooglePlus.execute(GooglePlus.java:70)
                 at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:117)
                 at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
                 at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
                 at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:57)
                 at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
                 at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
                 at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**This is in the config.xml file**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
    <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.****.****" />
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for the value in here:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
    <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.****.****" />
</plugin>
```

I had the exact same problem and realized I was passing my package id like `com.javebratt.packagename` when you actually pass the reverse web id in the Google Developers Console, so it's something like: `com.googleusercontent.apps.<uniqueIdHere>`

Then it started working half the time and breaking the other half, so I decided to pass the webId to the `login()` function and it started working without any problems.